# "Unknown" and "Invalid use of Null" errors when performing SQL queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

A customer of ours has encountered some strange behavior. Our software uses a database and we connect to it by the JET engine 4.0. We retrieve information by using SQL statements. So these commands are the same for every installation/user. We have a lot of customers but there is only one who encounters the following issue:

Some SQL statements cause strange errors:

```
SELECT * FROM Dimensions
```

=> Successful

```
SELECT * FROM Sections where true=false
```

=> Error : "Unknown"

```
SELECT Alpha, Ys, Zs FROM SectionProperties WHERE Id = 1
```

=> Error : "Invalid use of Null"

These statements run without a problem on any other machine.

Comment: I assume "JET engine" means Microsoft Access?

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of Jet at the client with problems. Probably needs an update.

Comment: The version of msjet40.dll is 4.0.9765.0
Seems up to date to me.

Comment: Re-apply the update anyway, in case it got trashed by some package with a bad install.